# Is there a way to set the number of inodes in VirtualBox when creating a VDI?

Tags: virtualbox, inode

Using VirtualBox 4.3.26 in a Windows 7 host to create Ubuntu 14.04 guest.

One of my main reasons to do so is process large numbers of small files, taking advantage of a SSD drive on the host.

I was quickly introduced to "the inode problem" in that context.

Standard advice out there seems to be create a new partition, set number of high nodes higher than default and migrate data there.

However, I cannot find a setting which allows me to set the number of inodes at the time of a VDI creation.

Is there actually a way to do this ... or do I need to simply create a sufficiently large VDI in order to get the required number of inodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new VDI to the guest, you need to create a filesystem from within the guest. If you create a filesystem i.e. ext4 then you can set the number of inodes with the `-N` parameter.

See also: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4 or `man mkfs.ext4`

Comment: Great ... thanks.  FWIW, this http://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup had all the info on required steps: fdisk, mkfs, fstab.